# master and content pages and jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to use jQuery in my ASP.NET 3.5 website that uses master pages and content pages. How do I do document ready() functions for the child pages for those that will use jQuery ? Where do I put the code?

I figured the jQuery declarations should go in the master page, but don't know how to make sure any jQuery calls go into the HEAD of the resolved page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put a content placeholder in the master's head section, and then write page-specific scripts withing the asp:Content tags of your pages.

**Master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="LocalScripts" runat="server" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master1.master" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" Title="MyTitle"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" Runat="Server" ContentPlaceHolderID="LocalScripts" >
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
           // some local script logic here
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Consider moving the `<script>` and `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` elements to right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use something like this:

**In child page** (*I don't think it matters greatly WHERE it is put in the page*):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Do work here
    });
</script>
```

as long as you have included the necessary jQuery files (libraries and plug-ins) in your master page.

Comment: This is true as long as the calls to `$(document).ready` occur *after* the jQuery library has been referenced.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` calls can be made anywhere on the page, not just in the head. If you do want your child pages to place additional scripts in the head area I'd suggest simply defining another ContentArea in your master page inside the head tags.